# Convert geometry data to KML File

Tags: shapefile, kml

I have a shapefile with size 200 Mb and when I convert it to KML it creates a 4.3 GB KML file, which I am unable to load in fusion table of Google. So I want to break it into a smaller KML file.

How to create small KML file from that shapefile or postgres table (that I create from shapefile using shp2pgsql command?

Comment: XML is simply larger than binary formats. I doubt there's anything you can do without removing a significant amount of data (features, attributes, vertices,  or a combination of all three).

Comment: Is your shapefile large because of large or complex geometries? If so, you're probably out of luck. But, if your shapefile is large because of lots of attribute data, then you might be able to reduce the file size enough by removing all the attribute data.  You could always load the geometries as one Fusion Table, and the attributes as a separate Fusion Table... and then join them back together in Fusion Tables.